# Не подключается к MySQL c#

Tags: c#, mysql

Изучаю работу в БД в c#. Решил законектиться к базе MySQL. Но подключение не открывается. Вот код:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Configuration;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace Test_MySql
{
    static class DB
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Database=test_db;port=3306;User Id=root;password=ТУТ МОЙ ПАРОЛЬ");
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Полное исключение(без `catch`):

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Не удается найти указанный файл.
File name: 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.AssertPermissions()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at Test_MySql.DB.Main(String[] args) in D:\visual\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\Program.cs:line 14
```

Вроде в ошибке все написано. Но не могу все таки понять, что я не так делаю. Локальный сервер точно существует, я им пользовался и пользуюсь в других языках в своих проектах. На приложении в `WinForms` Подключение работает. Но именно в этом примере ничего не работает.

Comment: А сама бд-то существует? Может вы её создать забыли?

Comment: Точно создал, в этом сомнений нет.

Comment: uid=root; а не User Id=root; попробуй вообще пример "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=12345;database=test"

Comment: А, так это исключение на стадии компиляции?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-string.html

Comment: Законектил. Всем спасибо)

Comment: Возможно, используется несовместимая версия `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`. Установите nuget-пакет именно для используемой версии .NET.

Comment: так укажите же , что конкретно помогло? ошибка была в строке подключения или еще что-то?

Comment: Ошибка была в строке подключения. Так же как посоветовали сверху, установил пакет через nuget. С ним так же все работает исправно